# Implement Objective-C (CoreML) in C++ (Adobe plugin)

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, coreml, after-effects

So I'd like to implement CoreML inside an Adobe After Effects plugin I'm developing.
Thing is that the After Effects SDK is in C++ (it is C compatible), and the CoreML API is in only Objective C and Swift.

All I want is the .plugin (the compiled After Effects plugin) to still work in After Effects with CoreML, I know there are magical tricks to make Objective C and normal C work together but have no idea how to make the After Effects SDK and CoreML work together, if this is even feasible in the first place as I only see old simple tutorials on how to implement Objective-C in C++.

The reason why I want to make this work is due to Apple deprecating OpenCL in Mac OS, leaving me with only CoreML as a GPU-accelerated deep learning framework.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your use case boils down to writing a library that calls another library that exposes a C++ API and also needs to interact with yet another library that exposes an Objective-C API.  If that is the case, you may want to try and come up with a small example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem(s) you are running into.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with After Effects plugin development specifically.

Comment: @AnatoliP Working with After Effects is just like writing a normal C++ application, I already have my plugin working with PyTorch C++'s API. I would've hoped all you needed to do was to choose an "compile to C++" option in XCode to compile Objective C to C++... But it is possible to use the Metal 2 API in C++, so I'd almost think it would be easier to run the specific CoreML model in custom C++ code, than to write 3 different libraries.

Comment: AFAIK, calling an Objective-C library from a C++ application is perfectly doable.  I think you should try it and ask specific questions here if you run into specific problems.  If there is a Metal 2 C++ API, you can call it directly from C++ code.  If CoreML provides Objective-C or Swift API only, you can still use it, but indirectly.  There is no such thing as compiling Objective-C to C++.  Objective-C and C++ are different, but related, languages that can be compiled to machine code.  Just do some studying and, I'm sure, you can figure this out.

Comment: So from what I understand, I will call all the CoreML functions that reside in an Objective-C executable/library file from the C++ Adobe plugin and pass the parameters and data to it? This doesn't seem to complex indeed. Thanks, I'll get to studying and will ask questions when they arise :D

Comment: I'm sure you will figure it out, and the SO community is always here to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, nGraph (also Tensorflow) with the PlaidML backend or the TVM compiler stack have both Metal acceleration support!